# Matplotlib makes empty plot using plt.plot but shows the plot using plt.scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am going to plot the results of a `for loop` and `if statement` inside of it.

I want to have plot with lines but once I use `plt.plot` the plot will be empty but once I try `scatter` I have plot with dots. What should I do to have plot of `Unu` vs `nu` with lines not dots?

```
if inp==0:
        print('***')
        print('0 Is not acceptable ')
        print('***')
    else:
        for xx in range(1,819):
            ...# lines of code
            if inp<0:
                if lim > 1:
                    pass
                else:
                    nu = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1] *115
                    plt.scatter(Unu(xx), nu)
            else:
                ...# lines of code
plt.show()
```

Comment: To plot lines you need more than one point (of course). Since you are plotting one point at a time, you can't see lines with `plt.plot`. Instead, what you need is to save your data points in some list/array and then plot them using `plt.plot`

Comment: @Sheldore yes, how can I do it at this code simultaneously with running the code

Comment: Initialize some lists after the first `else` and append them inside the second `else` with `nu` and `xx`. Then once the loop is finished, plot outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is not runnable but you can do something along the following lines:

- Initialize two lists to store `nu` and `Unu(xx)`
- Append them *inside* the for loop
- Plot them *outside* the for loop

---

```
if inp==0:
    print('***')
    print('0 Is not acceptable ')
    print('***')
else:
    nu_list = []
    Unu_list = []
    for xx in range(1,819):
        ...# lines of code
        if inp<0:
            if lim > 1:
                pass
            else:
                nu_list.append(dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1] *115)
                Unu_list.append(Unu(xx))
            plt.plot(Unu_list, nu_list)
        else:
            ...
plt.show()
```

Comment: Of course we have two `else`s. If you see we have one `else` after plot. this way indentations are wrong

Comment: I mean I bring the `plt` inside the `else` indentation under the `Unu_list.append)

Comment: @MaY : I fixed the indentation. Try now

Comment: could you tell me if `Unu(xx,t)`, and so we have two for loops one for `xx` and one for `t` how should to plot in order to have many lines (as many as len(t)) in one plot? I just added one for loop above the current for loop but the behavior of plot would be weird.

Comment: @MaY :  I think the plot command should be outside the `for xx` loop. That way, you will plot the whole xx range once for each t value. You should provide a complete code in your answer, only then it would be easier to answer your second question. Currently you have so many `else` that it is difficult to understand what's going on

Comment: just consider that instead of `Unu(xx), we have `Unu(xx, t), which needs two for loops

Comment: because when I add one loop, the ending and starting point of plots are connected to each other with straight line :| why